# Spring Saml secondary certificate in metadata

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml, adfs

I have a question about certificates generated in metadata (my SP). Our IdP says that when I change certificate I can publish it in metadata e.g. 20 days before as a secondary. Than IdP could load that, set trust and than (e.g. 5 days before expiration) my SP switch from secondary to primary.

Is it possible to set some certificate as a secondary? How could I do it?

I think that its quite common issue to change certificate, but I did not find such info about hierarchy of certificates in metadata.

We use spring security saml v1.0.1

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I added another property to my extendedMetadata and added another KeyDescriptor to spDescriptor and then it works - it generate metadata with two certificates with usageType SIGNING and ADFS server is able to load it. 
Note that you cant have a multiple encryption keys in metadata (if you work with ADFS - I dont know case of any other IdPs)

But new issue appeared. I have to sign my metadata and I found that if property with name

```
`<property name="signingKey" value="alias"/>`
```

is empty (certificate is old and I dont want to use it), metadata is not signed.
Could I use my custom property like

`<property name="signingKeySecondary" value="alias2" />`

to sign metadata?

Comment: Did you figure out a proper way to tackle this?